# Buffered geometry Uint16Array limitation?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am trying to optimize my code using buffered geometry (three.js).I was going through [Is there a limit of vertices in WebGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998278/is-there-a-limit-of-vertices-in-webgl/5843868#5843868). It seems I cannot comment on that question.
My question is on the 65k limit. Is this limit is on number of vertex indexes??
Or it is about each vertex index being smaller than 65k and the array can have more than 65k vertex indexes.

And need some good documentation on buffered geometry.

Answer (score 0):

The limitation is also there. You need to work with offsets to get around it with buffer geometry. see http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry.

I also gave a small explanation of how offsets work in https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4886#issuecomment-47198394

Comment: Thanks. And one more thing is it possible to implement selecting a geometry while using buffered approach (buffer with information of more than one geometry).

Comment: Their is no limitation on number of items in a uint16Array. It  can store any number of face indexes. But each face index must be smaller than 65535.